# Classes is not an AvaloniaProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to bind a value to the `Classes` property of some Avalonia Control from within a Style.
But I get a *Classes is not an AvaloniaProperty* error diagnostic.

The example below demonstrates the problem.

```xml
<Style Selector="Button">
    <Setter Property="Classes" Value="{Binding MyClasses}" />
</Style>
```

What is the correct way to bind to Classes from within a Style?

Note that in my application I have a proper reason to bind to the Classes property, unlike in the (contrived) example above which only serves to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to directly bind to `Classes` property in Avalonia, but there is a syntax that you might find useful:

```
<Button Classes.myClass="{Binding MyBoolean}"/>
```

It allows you to apply a style from the view model. It has been added quite recently and it is not mentioned in the documentation. You can find more details here:
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/5710